# SDL Tridion 2011 Event System - On Workflow Process Finish

Tags: tridion

I'm using the SDL Tridion event system to fire a method (`OnEmergencyRelease`) once a Workflow Activity has been completed. However my method isn't being entered during testing, where I'm stepping some components through the workflow process.

I'm subscribing using the following code:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, 
    FinishProcessEventArgs>(OnEmergencyRelease, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

But OnEmergency is never being entered:

```
private void OnEmergencyRelease(Component component, 
                                FinishProcessEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
   _log.Info("Emergency release entered");
}
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

I know the event system is being picked up as I write to the log in the constructor of my class.

Comment: What process are you attaching to? Do you know if your pdb files are in the correct place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't tell you for sure what happens, but I suspect that the FinishProcessEventArgs is not called on the Component object itself. Maybe you should try intercept on an object 'higher up' in the class hierarchy.

Example: use Process (or ProcessInstance or even IdentifiableObject)

`EventSystem.Subscribe<Process, FinishProcessEventArgs>(OnEmergencyRelease, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);`

Comment: Hi Mihai, that makes sense,  Will give it a shot and let you know, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If it works, please mark as answer :) You know... it's all about points, rep cred, badges and stuff :))

Comment: Hi Mihai, Yes, it works with RepositoryLocalObject.  I tried 'going up' one level to VersionedItem, but that didn't work.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Just for curiosity... what kind of RepositoryLocalObject it is? It must be something more specific than that...

Answer (score 0):

Is the event firing? I would expect Finish Process events to fire when you explicitly invoke a finish process action, and probably not when you step the items through.

Comment: Hi Dom, It fires now i'm using RepositoryLocalObject instead of Component.